# Is this valid approach to mock a function in pure C from scratch?

Tags: c, mocking, linker

```
// fakePow.c
#include <math.h>
double pow(double b, double p)
{ 
    return 6.0;
}
```

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int twice(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0)
        return 0;

    return x * 2;
}
int main()
{
    int x = pow(10, 2);
    int res = twice(x);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, I tried simple compilation, it didn't work, it returns 200 instead of 12

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c fakePow.c
gcc main.o fakePow.o -o main
./main

200
```

Then I found LD_PRELOAD with google, but it also doesn't work, as it returns 200 instead of 12

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -shared -o ./fakePow.so ./fakePow.c
LD_PRELOAD=./fakePow.so ./main

200
```

Comment: How would that code print 72 anyway? You mean 12 maybe?

Comment: @Mysterious Jack, I suspect `pow` is a reserved identifier and `pow(10, 2);`, with its _constant_ arguments is analyzed and evaluated at compile time into 200, thus your `pow()` is never called, but then nether is the `<math.h>` one either.  Perhaps you need to dis-able the compiler's analyzability?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes! it should be 12. I edited it. Sorry. Silly me

Answer (score 5):

> Is this valid approach to mock a function in pure C from scratch?

No. A C compiler may have built-in knowledge of the standard library routines, and yours is using that knowledge to evaluate `pow(10, 2)` during compilation, regardless of what definition you might provide for the function. This is permissible by the C standard because the names of the standard library routines are reserved, meaning the behavior is not defined if a program tries to use them for any other purpose.

Your compiler likely has a switch to turn off knowledge of the standard library routines. With Clang and GCC you can use `-fno-builtin-function` to disable treatment of `function` as a known function or `-fno-builtin` to disable knowledge of all built-in functions.

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that `-fno-builtin` and similar do not provide for *transparent* mocking.  They will at least sometimes produce different binaries (else what would be the point?), so a program built with this kind of accommodation for testing is not wholly equivalent to one built without.